# Detecting scrolling direction on the page - updating prev value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, ecmascript-6

I'm using React and I need to get a scroll direction in order to do some stuff. I have a working code but I'm clueless on how to store and **update** previous scroll position.

Here's my code:

```
componentDidMount(){
    const prev = window.scrollY;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', e => this.handleNavigation(e, prev);
}
```

Visible problem here is that componentDidMount **fires only once** so when I try to do the following:

```
handleNavigation = (e, prev) =>{
    const window = e.currentTarget;

    if(prev > window.scrollY){
        console.log("scrolling up");
    }
    else if(prev < window.scrollY){
        console.log("scrolling down");
    }
};
```

It compares values properly but **prev never changes**, so it doesn't work as intended. How do I make it work?

Do I put prev inside the interval to update the value or something crazy like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following. It should work since this way the previous value is stored in the instance of the component.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.prev = window.scrollY;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', e => this.handleNavigation(e));
}

handleNavigation = (e) => {
    const window = e.currentTarget;

    if (this.prev > window.scrollY) {
        console.log("scrolling up");
    } else if (this.prev < window.scrollY) {
        console.log("scrolling down");
    }
    this.prev = window.scrollY;
};
```

Comment: Yep, that's working and obvious solution. Thank you for unstucking my brain.

Comment: For those who are looking for more precise implementation in react hooks, it can be found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497110/detect-scroll-direction-in-react-js/62497293#62497293).

Comment: You can find an answer without any state management here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65534697/7207514